Circular Dependency with Custom Logger and Module in NestJS
Im getting a Circular Dependency error with a Module (UsersModule) and a Custom Logger (did it following this section of the documentation).
When the Logger instance is called inside the UsersModule I get the following error. ERROR [ExceptionHandler] A circular dependency has been detected inside UsersModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()". Note that circular relationships between custom providers (e.g., factories) are not supported since functions cannot be called more than once.. As soon as I remove any log inside the UsersModule the project starts with no problem.
On the other hand when calling the Logger inside any other Module there is no error.
Im expecting for the Logger instance to work on every Module
All Modules Have been registered on the AppModule

Can you provide the code in your users.module.ts and your custom logger please
